# limited number of items to display in an array in java

Tags: java

anyone has any idea how can I limit this program to print only 5 of the 20 elements of the array.

Greetings and thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class lot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n[] = {1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

        Random rd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(rd.nextInt(n[i]) + 1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I have an idea, use inner loop from 0 to 5. Also please follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and rename your class to begin with upper case.

Comment: substitute `i < n.length` in the for loop with `i < 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Lot {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n[] = {1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

        Random rd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.println(rd.nextInt(n[i]) + 1);
        }
    }

}
```

Learn how to use a for loop http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Java